# Log on to a PHP page remotely

Tags: php, security

Ok, let me try and explain what I am trying to achieve and I imagine I am going to get alot of stick for this.

I have a server setup with PHP and login, etc. already created.

Now I am working on a phone application and trying to leverage what I already have created, however I am really struggling to think of a secure way to login from the website because the only way I can see to do this is to call the PHP page with the password, e.g.:

```
http://website/login?password=password
```

My passwords are already salted but this will still not help because although the actually password will not be seen on the request, the request could be intercepted and resent repeatedly.

What can I do here to secure this up?

Comment: use POST and SSL. POST will prevent the password from showing up in server logs, and SSL will prevent sniffing while in transit.

Comment: @MarcB Why you didnt post this as an answer?

Comment: Not much of an answer, but if you insist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use POST and SSL. POST will prevent the password from showing up in server logs, and SSL will prevent sniffing while in transit.